# Prove Using Boolean Algebra

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, boolean-algebra

So here I have a question:
$$\neg (B-A)=(\neg B) \cup_{}^{}(A\cap_{}^{}B)$$

Note that the negation symbol is actually used to represent the compliment symbol because I could not find a symbol for the compliment. I came up with a solution for this and wanted to verify it. Instead of proving this by showing that they are subsets of each other, I will use boolean algebra to show it is logically equivalent, by first converting the set operations to boolean operations and use DeMorgan's Law. Would this be valid? Or should I stick to proving that they are subsets of each other?

Comment: Yes, it's valid since all the things you use hold in every Boolean algebra, in particular in a powerset. Complement can be typeset by `A^\complement`: $A^\complement$.

Comment: For complement, you can just use `$A^C$`=$A^C$ or `$\bar A$
`=$\bar A$.

Comment: You can replace $B$ by the statement $x\in B,A$ by the statement $x\in A$ and prove that the statements obtained are equivalent. That would prove the corresponding set equality. But note that whatever logical operations you want to carry out, you can do the same through set operators. DeMorgan's Law holds for sets as well.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Berci thank you both! Could I also get a solution as well so that I can check if I did it right?

Comment: A solution using set theory or boolean algebra?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I used boolean algebra.

Comment: if you do not have the time to provide a sample solution then could you make a quick explanation of the steps? I wanted to know if mine was right, I used the rule that (x in A) or (x in (not A)) is equivalent to x in the universe.